# Determining the intercepts of an equation

Tags: polynomials

My question says,

**Determine the following for equation $f(x) = 4x^2– 3x + 10$: X intercepts, Y intercepts, Domain, Range, End behaviour, and Number of possible turning points.**

I'm not sure how to determine the answers for the questions asked. My teacher did not explain it clearly. If anyone can give me some advice in determining the answer I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: X intercepts is when the curve intersects the $x$-axis (i.e. $y=f(x)=0$), Y intercepts is when $x=0$, domain is yhe set of all numbers you can substitute in the place of $x$, the range of the function is all the possible values that the function can attain (i.e. all numbers $a$ such that $f(x)=a$ for some $x$ in the domain)

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj So would the x intercept be 0 and the y intercept be 10?

Comment: The y intercept is true, but how did you get that x intercept is 0 ? Have you tried to solve $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm meaning that there would be 0 x intercepts. Is that true?

Comment: Yes that is true, we say that there is no $x$ intercepts which means that this curve will never intersect the $x$-axis